# Some shift+arrows not working in tmux?

Tags: tmux

I am attempting customize tmux so that

- Ctrl-Arrows are used for pane selection
- Shift-Arrows are used for pane resizing
- Alt-Arrows (left, right) are used for window selection

... all are working correctly, except for Shift-Up and Shift-Down.  (Puzzlingly, Shift-Left and Shift-Right work as expected.)

This is running tmux 2.0 inside xfce4-terminal (although I've also seen this problem on Ubuntu, using Ubuntu's default terminal program.)

Is there something I am not doing correctly?  Here is the entire contents of my .tmux.conf file:

```
# split <h>orizontal and <v>ertical
bind-key h split-window -v
bind-key v split-window -h

# Use Ctrl-arrow keys without prefix key to switch panes
bind -n C-Up    select-pane -U
bind -n C-Down  select-pane -D
bind -n C-Left  select-pane -L
bind -n C-Right select-pane -R

# Use Shift-arrow keys without prefix key to resize panes
bind -n S-Up    resize-pane -U
bind -n S-Down  resize-pane -D
bind -n S-Left  resize-pane -L
bind -n S-Right resize-pane -R

# Use Alt-arrow keys without prefix key to switch windows
bind -n M-Left  previous-window
bind -n M-Right next-window

# No delay for escape key press
set -sg escape-time 0

# Reload tmux config
bind-key r source-file ~/.config/.tmux.conf \; display-message "Configuration reloaded"
```

Comment: NOTE: I just tried this with `xterm` as my terminal app, but with the same results.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is unlikely to be related to some difference in *application mode* versus *normal mode*, because `xterm` sends the same sequence of characters for shifted and unshifted cursor keys.

One clue to the problem is that the various <kbd>ctrl</kbd> items are all *extended* `xterm` capabilities. `tmux` uses a couple of tables:

- one lists special keys which are unlikely to be found in a terminal entry
- the other lists terminal capabilities which might be gotten from a regular terminal database entry.

For the latter, these rows from `tmux`'s table are relevant:

```
    { TTYC_KDN2, TTYCODE_STRING, "kDN" },
    { TTYC_KDN3, TTYCODE_STRING, "kDN3" },
    { TTYC_KDN4, TTYCODE_STRING, "kDN4" },
    { TTYC_KDN5, TTYCODE_STRING, "kDN5" },
    { TTYC_KDN6, TTYCODE_STRING, "kDN6" },
    { TTYC_KDN7, TTYCODE_STRING, "kDN7" },
    { TTYC_KEND, TTYCODE_STRING, "kend" },

    { TTYC_KLFT2, TTYCODE_STRING, "kLFT" },
    { TTYC_KLFT3, TTYCODE_STRING, "kLFT3" },
    { TTYC_KLFT4, TTYCODE_STRING, "kLFT4" },
    { TTYC_KLFT5, TTYCODE_STRING, "kLFT5" },
    { TTYC_KLFT6, TTYCODE_STRING, "kLFT6" },
    { TTYC_KLFT7, TTYCODE_STRING, "kLFT7" },

    { TTYC_KRIT2, TTYCODE_STRING, "kRIT" },
    { TTYC_KRIT3, TTYCODE_STRING, "kRIT3" },
    { TTYC_KRIT4, TTYCODE_STRING, "kRIT4" },
    { TTYC_KRIT5, TTYCODE_STRING, "kRIT5" },
    { TTYC_KRIT6, TTYCODE_STRING, "kRIT6" },
    { TTYC_KRIT7, TTYCODE_STRING, "kRIT7" },
    { TTYC_KUP2, TTYCODE_STRING, "kUP" },
    { TTYC_KUP3, TTYCODE_STRING, "kUP3" },
    { TTYC_KUP4, TTYCODE_STRING, "kUP4" },
    { TTYC_KUP5, TTYCODE_STRING, "kUP5" },
    { TTYC_KUP6, TTYCODE_STRING, "kUP6" },
    { TTYC_KUP7, TTYCODE_STRING, "kUP7" },

    { TTYC_RI, TTYCODE_STRING, "ri" },
```

Most of these rows (in `tty-term.c`) are `xterm` extensions.  The strings for the shifted cursor keys might be provided by `"kUP"`, `"kDN"`, `"kLFT"`, `"kRGT"` — as well as `"kri"` and `"kind"`.

The last two are problematic:

- `tmux` has a table entry for `"ri"` (the string sent *to* the terminal) but none for `"kri"` and `"kind"` (your up/down cursor-keys)
- because (n)curses' [`wgetch`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_getch.3x.html) will see only the first capability with a given value in the list of strings, ncurses' database defines only *one* possibility.
- `kUP` and `kDN` are extensions, not standard capabilities, so ncurses defines `"kri"` and `"kind"`, which *are* standard.

The problem is not with your configuration, but a simple bug in `tmux` which could be addressed by adding entries to that table.  Something like this (untested) is a way to proceed:

```
    { TTYC_KUP2, TTYCODE_STRING, "kri" },
    { TTYC_KDN2, TTYCODE_STRING, "kind" },
```

Comment: Thank you for such a definitive answer!  I will attempt to recompile tmux with those lines added, and see what the results are.   One additional counterpoint:  I had forgotten about this, but I do *not* see this problem when I use the 'Secure Shell' ChromeOS app as my remote terminal.  How does that observation jive with your answer?

Comment: Note that replacing the existing KUP2 and KDN2 rows with your variants seemed to have no effect on the problem.

Comment: Later, when I have more time, I may attempt to watch tmux's reactions to these keypresses in a debugger.

Comment: Sounds as if the problem is deeper (though if I did not misread the source, the detail that I pointed out is likely part of the solution).  Knowing the actual `TERM` and terminal description (output of `infocmp` might help).

Comment: I agree; the problem does seem to be deeper.  Basically, every terminal program I use behaves slightly differently in this respect.   It will not work correctly at the console, or using PuTTY for ssh, but it will work correctly with old-fashioned `xterm`.   I'll update my question with `TERM` (for each of the above) and `infocmp` details after I experiment a little more.